# loop enumerate objects in radioButton

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hello i want to loop this object in checkbox value and index

```
 data: [
        {
        key1: 'last 6 months'
      },
      {
        key2: 'last 30 days'
      }
    ]
```

i want to create a radioButton like this

° last 6 months

° last 30 days

i'm do that in my code

```html
                  <div
                    v-for="index in data"
                    :key="index.id"
                  >
                    <radio-button
                      v-model="date"
                      :value="index"
                      :label="index"
                    />
                  </div>
```

my results is

° key1

° key2

i wan't to recover value in label not key because the key is send to api

Please help thank you

Comment: What if you `v-for="(key, index) in data"` and then use `key[index]` for both `value` and `label`? Meanwhile, this is not a checkbox and it's a pretty strange way of doing things. What is the end goal for this?

Comment: @kissu i edit my question sorry is a radio button not checkbox ```key[index]``` not work in label

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, it's an object! What about `(value, key, index) in data` and `data[key]` for `value`/`label`?

Comment: @kissu in label i add the last solution is not work my label add only the key

Comment: And if you try `value`?

Comment: is the same is add the key i don't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Iterate an object

When [iterating an object with `v-for`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#v-for-with-an-object), the object value is the first argument, then the object key. And since the object key is unique, you can use that as the `key` binding:

```html
<div v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="key">
```

The `label` prop of `<radio-button>` should be bound to the object value, which is descriptive text; and the `value` prop could be bound to either the object value or object key, depending on what you want the `v-model` to reflect:

```html
<radio-button v-model="date" :value="key" :label="value" />
```

The final result should be similiar to:

```html
<div v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="key">
  <radio-button name="my-date" v-model="date" :value="key" :label="value" />
</div>
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-binding-object-values-in-v-for?file=src/App.vue)

### Iterate an array of objects

Nest the solution above in another `v-for`. The outer `v-for` iterates the array, while the inner one iterates the the object:

```html
<template v-for="item in data">
  <div v-for="(value, key) in item" :key="key">
    <radio-button name="my-date" v-model="date" :value="key" :label="value" />
  </div>
</template>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-binding-object-values-in-v-for-csoakx?file=src/App.vue)